# What are the best user data collection and gathering tracking tools?

Tags: google, tracking, data, tools

I know of a few tool that help markets gather data about visitors, Google Analytic, CrazzyEgg, and KISS Insights.

What are other notable tools to help track information? What do you use?

Comment: What I'd love to see is a service similar to those, which allows uploading of server side logs to validate the data. More often than not, server side stats disagree entirely with many JS driven analytics programs.

Comment: @tim thats mainly because bots don't have JS, so they don't appear in items such as Google analytics, but they do appear in your server logs. And there are A LOT or bots.

Comment: @corymathews true, but it would be nice to get direct file downloads in the logs too (where the user didn't click JS event-tagged links)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of them is Shaun Inman's [Mint](http://haveamint.com/).

Then:

1. [VisiStat](http://www.visistat.com/)
2. [SiteCatalyst](http://www.omniture.com/en/products/online_analytics/sitecatalyst)
3. [Webtrends](http://www.webtrends.com/Products/Analytics)
4. [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
5. [ClickTraks](http://www.lyris.com/solutions/lyris-hq/web-analytics/)
6. [Coradiant](http://www.coradiant.com/products/analytics_in_a_box.htm)
7. [Unica](http://www.unica.com/products/enterprise-web-analytics.htm)
8. [pMetrics](http://pmetrics.performancing.com/)
9. [Clicky](http://www.getclicky.com/)
10. [iWebTrack](http://www.iwebtrack.com/reports.asp)
11. [OneStat](http://www.onestat.com/html/services.html)
12. [MetaTraffic](http://www.metasun.com/products/metatraffic/features.asp)
13. [Metronome](http://www.metronomelabs.com/)
14. [Clicktale](http://www.clicktale.com/)
15. [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
16. [Observer](http://observerapp.com/)
17. [W3Counter](http://www.w3counter.com)
18. [KISSMetrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com)
19. [MixPanel](http://www.mixpanel.com)

Comment: Are any of these particularly suited for handling a large portfolio of sites?

Answer (score 1):

no love for [ChartBeat](http://chartbeat.com/) or [Quantcast](http://www.quantcast.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

[Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) is another solution. Unfortunately it has not been updated since 2005 though.

Answer (score 0):

Among the free tools that offer the most features, Clicky & StatCounter look promising. [See comparison chart](http://www.getclicky.com/#theotherguys)

Both have paid plans as well.

I've been using the free version of StatCounter on my blog since 5 years & I'm pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/): Open source real time analytics. I don't use this, but I have a friend who does and he really likes it. It does look pretty nice and with something like this you can do all sorts of other things with the data (such as your own real time stats on the website).

Also, [here is a list of alternatives](http://regulargeek.com/2010/05/29/25-free-google-analytics-alternatives/). It has log file analyzers, like Analog or AWStats, remote services, like stat24 and Yahoo Analytics, and self hosted, like Open Web Analytics and FireStats.